# Can't use YouTube-dl to download specified bitrate

Tags: youtube-dl

After needing something both easy and powerful that would allow me to download YouTube playlists and finding no better alternative, I've recently started using youtube-dl (with ffmpeg) in the command line. I'm currently in the process of playing around with and testing the quality of my downloaded playlists, but I've run into a problem converting a playlist to M4A audio at 192kbps. Here is what I'm using:

`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format m4a --audio-quality 192 --playlist-items 1-26 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLR3nWwHlZ9WBpi3uWsjSe6r1PiA8MTbnE`

The `--audio-quality 192` doesn't seem to be registering, even though the syntax seems right as far as I can tell, and when the audio files are downloaded and extracted, they consist of a whole range of different bitrates, from 189 to 254. Can anyone tell me why I might be having this problem?

Comment: I'm not understanding why I'm being downvoted for this?

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Comment: It belongs here enough to generate a tag with over a hundred uses, as well as a long history of (non-downvoted) answers around the same topic - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youtube-dl - hence what attracted me here to ask the question. I don't see why mine is any different.

Comment: Can you recommend anywhere else that it would be more appropriate?

Comment: The question is fine with the `youtube-dl` tag.  The only other place would be the youtube-dl IRC channel: [irc://chat.freenode.net/#youtube-dl] for live chat, or posting an issue on the youtube-dl tracker [https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues]

Comment: @Mekki There being a tag about something doesn't mean that all questions about that tag are on-topic, they still have to be about programming which this one (and, admittedly, a lot of other questions in this tag) is not.

Comment: @TZHX I disagree.  From [http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic]: "if your question generally covers" ... "software tools commonly used by programmer".  `Youtube-dl`, and, particulary, `ffmpeg` qualify enough that maybe he doesn't need to be downvoted into hell.  At east offer him an alternative.  Based on the StackExchange sites, it seems that [http://superuser.com/] probably would have been a better choice, but being too restrictive makes us seem like jerks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the `youtube-dl` helpfile, for bitrate, you need to specify the `K` after `192`.  Otherwise it treats it as variable bit rate:

> -audio-quality QUALITY          Specify ffmpeg/avconv audio quality,
>   insert
>                                    a value between 0 (better) and 9 (worse)
>                                    for VBR or a specific bitrate like 128K
>                                    (default 5)

See: [Post Processing Options in helpfile](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#post-processing-options)

UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT: There are open issues suggesting that ffmpeg does not report all the errors it faces when processing, particularly the mp4 (m4a) codec.  See [Issue 8230](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/8230).  An alternative format may be a workaround.  Another workaround may be changing the system's mp4 codecs such that ffmpeg is happier with them.

If neither of these workarounds work for you, please post the output of running the command with the `--verbose` option so that we can see the debug info.

UPDATED SINCE DOESN'T AFFECT MP3s:

Since `ffmpeg` is known to have some mp4 codec issues, another thing you can try is use `avconv` and `avprobe` instead of `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` as post-processors for `youtube-dl`.  You can download the latest Windows binaries here: [LibAV Windows binaries](http://builds.libav.org/windows/release-gpl/).  Don't forget to add the executables to your `PATH` system environment variable so that `youtube-dl` can find them.

Then add the `--prefer-avconv` option in your `youtube-dl` command and see if it behaves better.

EDIT WITH KNOWN-BUG DETAILS:

It seems you may have tripped over a previously-missed version of this bug [M4a Audio file post-processing skipped](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/2288) - While the developer has addressed the slightly different case in the bug description, it seems to occur in your case as well.  It may be worth posting the details to the `youtube-dl` [Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues).

Switching to a different format (like `mp3`) may be the only workaround at this point.

Comment: I tried this first, before seeing it without the k on another site and trying 192 on its own. Neither seem to work.

Comment: If you use an audio format other than `m4a` do you still see the whole range of different bitrates?

Comment: Just tried this with MP3s, and it behaves as it should - all downloaded files are 192kb. Couldn't test it with any other format because the only other audio format available to download audio comes from webm/opus, which doesn't support a constant bitrate at all, so won't display one.

Comment: Did the debugging, here are the results. Click the green link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00496685513368586277. All the files that I downloaded came out as 253kpbs, apart from one which was 254.

Comment: In the log, it shows that all the post-processing in `ffmpeg` is being skipped because the files already exist.  Are you trying to overwrite the previously downloaded files with the non-192k bit-rates?  If so, please try with an empty folder and post again so that the post-processing actually runs.  

If the folder was already empty, then for some reason `ffmpeg` is seeing the files as already existing and skipping:

`[ffmpeg] Post-process file B:\Users\Hashim\Desktop\New Folder\Rihanna And Kanye
West And Paul McCartney - FourFiveSeconds.m4a exists, skipping`

Comment: Also, for sake of debugging, add the `--fixup warn` option, so that we can see if the auto-correction `[ffmpeg] Correcting container in...` is causing the problem.

Comment: Nope, all downloading is being done to a new folder. The program has always given that as output since I've used it, so I've always assumed it was just an idiosyncrasy, the way it chooses to word the usual process of post-processing, rather than something to be worried about. I'll do another debug with --fixup warn now.

Comment: It looks like the `-y` option is supposed to overwrite files by default without prompting anyways, so that's probably not it.  It's increasingly looking like an `ffmpeg` `mp4` codec compatibility thing.

Comment: What does `-y` do? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: It's an `ffmpeg` option, not `youtube-dl`: [ https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options ] - Your log shows that `youtube-dl` uses the `-y` option when issuing the post-processing calls to `ffmpeg`, which should mean that `ffmpeg` will overwrite files by default and that's not the issue, contrary to what I suspected above.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll try avconv and avprob now. I've just downloaded one of the libav releases - do I need to copy all the files in it - DLLs and all - into the same folder as youtube-dl, or will just avconv and avprob be enough?

Comment: Copy all the files with their folder structure intact (`bin`, `lib`, etc.) somewhere on your computer,  and then make sure your `PATH` environment file points  to the `bin` location.  That should be enough.  I'm not sure exactly which other files in the install `avconv` & `avprobe` depend on, so this approach is safer.

Comment: Alternatively, use the `--ffmpeg-location PATH` option in your `youtube-dl` call where `PATH` is the fully qualified location of where you installed the `bin` folder.

Comment: Come to think of it, all I ever did with ffmpeg was copy `ffmpeg.exe` and `ffprobe.exe` into the same folder youtube-dl was in, and then had the environment file point to the folder they're all in; didn't copy anything else in. Do you reckon that could be the problem?

Comment: That's entirely possible.  Try a full `ffmpeg` install to ensure all the dependencies are there.

Comment: I double-checked - I downloaded a static build from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds, where it says that static builds "provide one self-contained .exe file for each program (ffmpeg, ffprobe, ffplay)", so theoretically, that should be fine? 

I'll do that with avprobe now though.

Comment: See edit to answer.  May be a known `youtube-dl` bug that wasn't fully fixed with `m4a` format. Might not be `ffmpeg`'s fault afterall.

Comment: Fair enough. After trying for what seems like ages, I'm unable to get `avprobe` and `avconv` working, so it looks like I'm resigned to submitting this bug and waiting for the developers to sort it out. Thanks for your help, @Mekki, it's much appreciated.